# Add protected and internal visibility to function in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have an `open` (or `abstract`) `public` `class` that contains an `open` (or `abstract`) `fun` (or `var` or `val`) that I do not want to expose as `public`.

Unfortunately I also need to call that `fun` from inside my current package.
If I mark it as `internal` that class cannot be inherited correctly from another package(ide gives warning: inherits invisible abstract members), if I mark it as `protected` the fun cannot be access from inside the current package

Any way to bypass this?

Answer (score 2):

A dirty way is to add a proxy internal method and call that method inside your package:

```
abstract class AbstractClass {
    protected abstract fun isTrue(int: Int): Boolean

    internal fun isTrueInternalProxy(int: Int): Boolean {
        return isTrue(int)
    }
}
```